# ordenar Meses como calendario SQL y traducirlos meses a español Script Case

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, date

Trabajo en Script Case 9.3.0006  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  14.0.17285.0
Buenas tardes foro tengo una duda sobre Script Case  lo que pasa estoy metiendo un query sql  que hace que me cuente por cada mes  hace todo bien sin ningun problema, el problema que tengo es que  los meses los mete en ingles y he configurado Script en español pero no cambia, no se si sea problema del query o digamen como configuro para que me los convierta a español.
Tambien si me pueden ayudar a ponerlo en orden de calendario no se si sea igual el query o Script.
De antemano gracias a sus respuestas.
estes es mi query

```
SELECT  
COUNT (no_solicitud) AS SOLICITUDES ,
year (fecha_registrada) as anos ,
DATEname ( month , (fecha_registrada) ) as MES
FROM LIT_SRCartera
where
YEAR ( fecha_registrada ) = YEAR ( DATEADD ( year , 0 , getdate() ) ) and 
month (fecha_registrada) > = month ( DATEadd ( month , -4 , GETDATE() ) )
GROUP BY year (fecha_registrada) , DATEname ( month , (fecha_registrada)       ) 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT ( no_solicitud ) AS SOLICITUDES , 
YEAR (fecha_registrada) AS ANOS ,
DATEname ( month , (fecha_registrada) ) as MES
FROM LIT_SRCartera
where YEAR (fecha_registrada) = YEAR ( DATEADD ( year , 0 , getdate() ) ) or 
YEAR ( fecha_registrada ) = YEAR ( DATEADD ( year , -1 ,  getdate() ) ) or
YEAR (fecha_registrada) = YEAR ( DATEADD ( year , -2, getdate() ) )
and fecha_registrada is not null
GROUP BY YEAR (fecha_registrada), DATEname ( month, (fecha_registrada) )
```

Comment: Prueba agregar la siguiente sentencia de orden al final del script: `ORDER BY YEAR (fecha_registrada), DATEPART( month, (fecha_registrada) )`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el lenguaje por defecto del usuario que ejecuta la acción con una llamada a `sp_defaultlanguage`:

```
sp_defaultlanguage @loginame = 'login' , @language = 'language'
```

O también puedes asignar el lenguaje de la sesión al momento de ejecutar la consulta.

```
SET LANGUAGE spanish
Select 
DATEname ( month , (fecha_registrada) ) as MES
```

De esta manera puedes tener el resultado que gustas. O bien crear tu propia función que retorne el nombre del mes.

Suerte.